# Port Andengine game to other platform?

Tags: android, flash, andengine, libgdx

I'm planning on writing a multiplayer game with Android as my primary focus as far as OS/platform, but I would like the ability to port the game to at least the web.  I'm looking into Andengine as I'm just starting out with java and android and it seems the most noob friendly.  The game shouldn't be too demanding as it will be a 2d turn based game with simple animations and chat.

1. So my main question - is it possible to port a Andengine game to the web?
2. If not what would you suggest?
3. I looked at libgdx, but I'm concerned that it might be a little to advanced for someone just starting out with java/android.  Am I correct in my assumption?
4. Another idea I've been playing around with is writing the game in Flash and porting it to Android with Adobe Air - does anyone have any experience with this?  Is it a bad idea?  I kind of have my doubts of how well this will work, but if nobody can really talk me down from this idea, I might just go this route.

I've also considered writing the game in pygame as it seems easier but I don't like the idea of players having to download something like Pygame Subset for Android or Kivy to run the game.  So basically if the other options are either too difficult or wont work on android then I'm probably just going to go with Andengine and consider rewriting it later for the web if people like it enough.

Comment: By "porting to the web" you mean a game which runs on the browser, like a java applet?

Comment: yeah, basically I would like to be able to deploy a browser version with minimal effort.

Comment: AndEngine is based on Android, therefore does not run on a browser. But if you keep your game logic apart from platform dependent code, you could deploy any version with a minimal effort.

Comment: Sounds good, do you have any recommendations as to where I should start? I've already began learning java.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Moai SDK](http://getmoai.com) is an open source multi-platform framework for game developers.
One codes in lua - a dynamic programming language (that is easy to learn).
Apps made using Moai can be deployed to iOS, android and the chrome web store.

Moai could be an alternative.

Comment: Was unaware of this project. Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to look into this, sounds like a win win - Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Andengine makes a fine starting place. (I have made 3 projects with it now and I really like it). but it does not deploy to anything other than android. That is its strength and its weakness. As a strength, it is very easy to integrate android OS features and libraries with your project and has good performance. And as a weakness, well, it only runs on android.

Code-once publish anywhere platforms trade off development time for speed and size usually. 
Some top competitors in that area are:

- Ancsa Corona
- AppMobi
- PhoneGap
- Unity3D
- Adobe Flash(bonus of web distribution)
- and others. (Moai SDK listed by @andrew, for example)

Each platform has had successful games launched with them. Find the one that suits you and your projects needs best. Do not forget to check for things you will want to integrate, such as using Facebook for mobile, or AdMob, or OpenFeint or other 3rd party services.

Good luck and enjoy you game making!

Answer (score 1):

Just a side note, user do not need to download "Kivy" to run the game. As other toolkit, your application will provide Kivy as other libraries you'll use.

Comment: Good to know, I'm going to reconsider Kivy because Python comes so highly reconmened